# Is Naruto an awful parent because Boruto is a brat?

Tags: naruto, boruto

I'm only up to episode 5 in the *Boruto* anime but the intro instantly implied what I thought and after watching the first few episode it certainly suggests that Boruto is a brat.

Does this point/suggest that Naruto might be too blame for this situation?

Comment: This question could receive additional valuable answers in: https://parenting.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can also read the manga, which happens after the events presented in the anime, where you can see a big difference in the relationship between Boruto and Naruto, by no means is Naruto an awful parent, it's clear he tries to figure out how to combine family and "family" (the village) and does his best for that (even in the anime, tho only like, twice up until now). Also harsh father doesn't mean bad father.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, and no. [Boruto](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boruto_Uzumaki) acts rebellious and resentful towards Naruto as he felt that his father being Hokage took him away from his family.

> Initially nonchalant in his duties as a member of Team Konohamaru and is resentful of his father and the office of Hokage because it left him with no time for his family

Eventually Boruto and Naruto do come eye to eye in this aspect

> Boruto eventually comes to respect and reconcile with his father and his role as Hokage

However, most of Boruto’s arrogance comes from his lineage and believes he is better than everyone else

> For these reasons, Boruto has a high opinion of himself and freely brags about his abilities, but his arrogance has made him put no value in teammates or teamwork, believing he can do anything on his own

Comment: Then I will wait for the story to unfold :D

Comment: Like Father Like Son, isn't it? The real function of bloodline ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, I wouldn't call Boruto a brat. I'd term him stubborn. Being the son of arguably the greatest shinobi/Hokage, Boruto is always known and accepted as his father's son. He feels that he has no identity for himself apart from being the 'Seventh's Son...!!!' which is why he despises his father. Naruto, who can take down an entire Zetsu army, fails at being a father because he himself had no father (Iruka, Jiraiya, Kakashi were close to father figures) and doesn't know how to acknowledge his child. Boruto despises that fact. He wants to rise above than being his father's son which he mistakes to be better than his father. Not only in terms of nature, but also in strength.

Boruto, like any kid, has a lot of love for his mother and Himawari and cannot stand to see them unhappy. So it's natural for him to feel that his father doesn't have time to spend with his family at important occasions like Himawari's birthday. He doesn't understand what it's to be a Hokage, at least until the later episodes where he remarks that he still hasn't understood his father yet.

In his mindset, he feels that becoming stronger than Naruto would be a great way to get back at Naruto. Knowing that his father has only one person who can match up to his level. He tries to learn from him.